# Why can not I run two or more times my thread?

Tags: multithreading, lazarus, freepascal

Why can not I run two or more times my thread. (The second call in the code does not work). In the procedure "Execute" there is no loop and behaves as if all the time working.

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin  
do_something();
end;


procedure TForm1.Do;
var DrawerA:TMyThread;
begin

DrawerA:=TMyThread.Create(True); 
DrawerA.Priority:=tpNormal; 
DrawerA.FreeOnTerminate:=False;           


DrawerA.Start;
DrawerA.WaitFor;


DrawerA.Start;
DrawerA.WaitFor;

{
if( Not DrawerA.Suspended) then DrawerA.Start
else DrawerA.Resume;    
}
```

end;

Comment: "The second call in the code does not work" - Do you receive an exception? What is the exact misbehavior you are facing?

Comment: After all the code in the Execute method is run your thread cannot be restarted. You will have to free and create another instance of the thread type you need. It's common to include while not Terminated do begin ... end around the code inside the Execute method in order to use a thread multiple times without having to recreate it.

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

A thread executes its thread procedure and then terminates. If you want a thread to perform multiple tasks, then you need to build the iteration into the thread procedure.